# How to update object after insert/update

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

We have triggers for some of our tables such that they update the inserted/modified entity after every put operation.

How can I instruct Hibernate to read the entity immediately after a put () operation so that the application always has access to the most accurate data read from the DB (including the data modified by triggers).
For the sake of simplicity, assume that triggers fire immediately after the put() operation.

I am looking for an annotation like select-after-update or select-after-insert.
Even better solution would be if I can specify the columns to read after insert/update.

**Update:**

@Generated annotation does not work in my case because I am using @ColumnTransformer annotation for modifiedDate field as described [here](http://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Hibernate/Chapter_08_-_Custom_SQL_for_Columns.jsp).

@Generated fails here completely as it leads Hibernate to believe that database would generate value for it. So the custom-write-SQL specified over columns is ignored during insert/update.

I want the reload functionality from the @Generated annotation but without the ignoring field part during insert/update.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [the @Generated annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-generated).

Comment: Thanks JB. Only issue I see with this approach is that if this annotation is applied to a base-class' field, Hibernate issues as many select commands as there are entities in the hierarchy.

Is there an annotation which can be specified at a class level such that it will load all the objects under the root object in one go? A single big select command would be more efficient in such a case.

Comment: This is a rarely used feature, known to be inefficient (since ever insert/update requires an additional select), and I doubt Hibernate has made everything it can to optimize it. That said, I don't see why it would issue many selects, and not just the one required to load the entity state.

Comment: I have tested it just now. Scenario is:
entity A has list of entity B objects.
Both A and B derive from a base class BASE.
Now BASE class has a field modifiedDate which is generated by the DB.

When I do a put, Hibernate generates insert commands for all the A and B objects.

However, it also generates a select command per entity.
So if A has 5 B objects, 6 select commands are generated.

If there was just a single select to load all Bs with A (even if we select all fields of A and B), it would perform better.
Note that I am talking of objects with much larger hierarchies.

Comment: JB Nizet, I have updated my question why @Generated is not working for my case (even if we leave the performance issue aside). Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't follow you. You first said that the value was generated by the database, and now you say that it's generated by your code. If it's generated by your code, you don't need to refresh anything. Anyway, I wouldn't use triggers for modifiedDate fields. Use entity listeners instead (PreInsert, PreUpdate JPA callbacks).

Comment: It is not generated by trigger but it is generated by the database due to custom-write-SQL (Please see the link in my updated question above) and so the generated value is not available to me during the update.

Comment: As I said: this is not a good way to handle this use-case. Use PreInsert and PreUpdate callbacks instead, whichwill initialize the fields of the entity to the current date, before its state is saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done in a single operation. As you said @Generated will simply ignore the column and @PostPersist and @PostUpdate cannot invoke EntityManager or queries (see documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html_single/#d0e2985)

Morever, if you do it in the same transaction, what guarantees you the execution of the trigger is finished when you try to load the data again?

As I see it, your only way out is a refresh() after the save or update on the object, in an other transaction.

Comment: Julien, I was looking for an annotation which does half the job of @Generated i.e. it only reads the value of specified field after insert/update without suppressing its population during insert/update.

In the case of Generated, Hibernate is assuming that value is purely generated by the database without taking into account that user may have specified some SQL for such a field which will be executed on the database side to generate a value for that field.

In other words, some annotation which lets Hibernate write the custom SQL during insert/update and then allows it to read the same too.

Comment: I see what you want to achieve and @Generated definitely doesn't do the job, I agree. Unfortunately, it looks like JPA/Hibernate doesn't offer this kind of functionnality, and even banned such behavior by restraining the use of PostPersist and PostUpdate.